# Rebuild of label index in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, lucene

My Neo4J instance suddenly stopped working, I think my drive ran out of space due to some unrelated logfiles. Anyway, now I cannot start Neo4J, it start, over and over again. If i check the consistency of the database I get the following message. (It does not work neither on version 3.3.5 or 3.4.1)

> WARN : Label index was not properly shutdown and rebuild is required.
>           Label index: neostore.labelscanstore.db
>   WARN : Index was not properly shutdown and rebuild is required.
>           Index[ IndexRule[id=1, descriptor=Index( GENERAL, :label0 ), provider={key=lucene, version=1.0}] ]
>   WARN : Index was not properly shutdown and rebuild is required.
>           Index[ IndexRule[id=3, descriptor=Index( GENERAL, :label1 ), provider={key=lucene, version=1.0}] ]

I see that there are a few very old answers related to something that might be similar. Are they still valid or how am I supposed to solve this?

When I try to start Neo4J I get

> Nov 23 15:36:08 v22018054377066500.supersrv.de systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
>   Nov 23 15:36:08 v22018054377066500.supersrv.de systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>   Nov 23 15:36:08 v22018054377066500.supersrv.de systemd[1]: Failed to start Neo4j Graph Database.
>   root@v22018054377066500:~# service neo4j start
>   root@v22018054377066500:~# service neo4j status
>   ● neo4j.service - Neo4j Graph Database
>      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-11-23 15:36:21 CET; 2ms ago
>     Process: 22073 ExecStart=/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j console (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, I was in the same starting situation. At the end of the day the removal and recreation of all indices and constrains solved my issue.

```
DROP INDEX ON :Person(name)
DROP CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.name IS UNIQUE

CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.name IS UNIQUE
```

Comment: I thought about the same, but I cannot start the database. I have updated the question with the error message i get when starting neo4j

Comment: I ended up exporting to Graphml and importing again, that solved it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up exporting to Graphml using apoc and importing again, that solved it