# Node(ID) already exists with label `X` and property 'Y'

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-driver

I'm creating nodes with `CREATE` command like the following:

```
CREATE (d:A { name:'one_string' })
```

when I run such a query, I get the following error message:

```
Node(12079) already exists with label `B` and property `name` = 'a_different_string'
```

As you see, I'm creating a node with a **different** *label* and *property* value and still get such an error. And, I don't really understand why running such a query should throw an error (note: I've defined a *constraint* on names of all types of Labels to be UNIQUE.)

One point is that, since I'm testing my graph building process multiple times, every time that I want to create nodes from the beginning, I first delete all the existing nodes using the following command:

```
MATCH (a:A) DELETE a
```

I'm wondering if this may cause the problem?

> **Edit:** I'm running the queries in python using the [neo4j python driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver) version 1.7.4 and when I run the exact command --from which I get an error-- in the neo4j desktop command-line I don't get any error.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j? And is that CREATE the entirety of the query? Or only a snippet?

Comment: @InverseFalcon good question, please see the edit. And, the CREATE is the only command that I have in my query.

Comment: You've given us the version of the python driver, could you give us the Neo4j version too?

Comment: @InverseFalcon the Desktop version I'm using is 1.2.1 and it tells me my Neo4j is 3.5.6 Enterprise, does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks. Deleting nodes shouldn't have anything to do with this. This is a very odd situation, can you shut down the instance and use [the consistency checker](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/consistency-checker/) to see if anything's off about your db? Also, do you have any logs from the client side, on the Cypher that it's attempting to send to the server?

Comment: @InverseFalcon this is the report after running the consistency checker:

`WARN : Label index was not properly shutdown and rebuild is required. Label index: neostore.labelscanstore.db
WARN : Index was not properly shutdown and rebuild is required. Index[ IndexRule[id=1, descriptor=Index( UNIQUE, :label[0](property[0]) ), provider={key=native$
WARN : Index was not properly shutdown and rebuild is required. Index[ IndexRule[id=8, descriptor=Index( UNIQUE, :label[1](property[0]) ), provider={key=native$`

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53445532/974731